# Looking for DEX code to create an internal token swap

Tags: solidity, decentralized-exchange

I'm currently working on a project with a token contract and I need to add an internal token swap feature. So to avoid writing everything from scratch i'm Looking for any GitHub repositories or open-source DEX projects that provide DEX code. I don't wanna go crazy with complicated code like uniswap. just need some simple swap for two tokens with liquidity implemented.